# unable to show the list in dropdown on editing a record

Tags: php, mysql

in my page when a user login into his acount there are two fields name and project so whenever he login his named filled in name field and his all projects are listed in dropdown in project field.my problem is tha when i edit this record it shows me the name and the project selected by him on submission but i want that on edit his all project will b listed there as on submission time.

Here is my project code for dropdown on submission time:

```
<tr>
           <td>Select Project</td>
           <td>
           <select id="project" name="project">
           <option value="">-- select --</option>
           <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
              {
                 $pm = $row['assignpm'];
                 $assignpm = explode(",",$pm);
                 if(in_array($_SESSION['id'], $assignpm)){ ?>

               <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['projectname']);?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['projectname']); ?></option>
 <?php } }?> 
             </select></td>
         </tr>
```

and here is my code for project field on editing:

```
<tr>
           <td>Select Project</td>
           <td><select name="project" id="project" style="width:145px">
               <option>Select</option>
              <option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $fetuser1['project'];?>"><?php echo $fetuser1['project'];?></option>       
                 </select></td>
         </tr>
```

Comment: Help me guys.its realu urgent for me

Comment: It's really hard to tell what exactly you are asking for... Could you explain your problem with other words and... welll... punctuation? Or maybe give an example of how the output is now and how you want it to be instead.

Comment: In short, you need to fetch all projects in the 2nd code snippet just like you do in the first code snippet.

Comment: in my form a project manager login into his acount where he has to fill his request about any thing. so when he login there are fields as project manager name , his projects listings and etc. he can select any of his project from drop down and process ahead. but when he edit his record then in dropdown there is only the selected project which he select on submission time and i want that there will b all his project listed as befor on submission time. is it possible??

Comment: @ickmund: yes exactly that

Answer (score 0):

So when editing you must do things much the same as on "submission time".

```
<tr>
    <td>Select Project</td>
    <td>
        <select name="project" id="project" style="width:145px">
            <option>Select</option>
            <?php 
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $pm = $row['assignpm'];
                    $assignpm = explode(",",$pm);
                    if(in_array($_SESSION['id'], $assignpm)) {
                ?>
                <option 
                    <?php if($fetchuser1['project'] == $row['projectname']) echo "selected='selected'";?> 
                    value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['projectname']);?>"
                >
                    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['projectname']); ?>
                </option>
            <?php } }?>
        </select>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: You obviously need to add the code to fetch the data from the database, code that you are not providing even in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

depends...
what do your query look like?
one query? two querys? one on the userid, name and stuff and another on the projects...

or are all project in the same table as the fetched username?
and how are thy stored (blob, json, simple list)?

And last: mixing php inline with html is a very bad habbit ;)

say you have two querys

```
//query SELECT projectname FROM whatevertable WHERE userid = 'users-id'

$options = "<option value="">-- select --</option>".PHP_EOL;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if(htmlspecialchars($row['projectname']) == $_SESSION['preselected']) //whatever
        $options. = "<option selected="selected" value=".htmlspecialchars($row['projectname']).">".htmlspecialchars($row['projectname'])."</option>".PHP_EOL;
    else
        $options. = "<option value=".htmlspecialchars($row['projectname']).">".htmlspecialchars($row['projectname'])."</option>".PHP_EOL;
}
```

and after all the php code you can

```
echo "<td>Select Project</td>
<td>
    <select id=/"project/" name=/"project/">
        {$options}
    </select>
</td>";
```

But without knowing any of your code but that little php-mixed-html it's hard to answer precisely